# but_velodyne with VLP16

Tags: velodyne, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [but_velodyne wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/but_velodyne) states that the package has been tested only with Velodyne HDL-32E. I am wondering if anyone has tried using the package with VLP16 or is aware of a reason why it would not work with VLP16?

I am looking for ways to colorize point cloud generated by VLP16 and am starting to investigate if [but_calibration_camera_velodyne](http://but_calibration_camera_velodyne) can do that. Has anyone used this node to colorize point clouds? What were the results?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244101/but_velodyne-with-vlp16/) by [chukcha2](https://answers.ros.org/users/25963/chukcha2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 89 on 2016-09-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have not used but_velodyne, and don't know whether VLP-16 support has been added. That device returns data in a slightly different format, so it won't work automatically.

The [velodyne driver](http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne_driver) in ros-drivers *does* support the VLP-16, if you build it from source.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2016-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0